# Replacing unknown special characters from string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I have a string which has a special character `—` this is called em-dash. I want to replace this character from my string using javascript, in both Windows and Linux.

It works well in Windows and I used this

```
mystring.replace(/—/, "-");
```

works, but in Linux that character `—` em-dash is shown as a black diamond with a question mark �

How do I match this character and replace to something?

`\u2014` = em-dash unicode

```js
let string = 'SampleTestcase—Temp';

if (string.match("\u2014")) {
     console.log("YES ITS MATCHED and its Em-dash");
     string = string.replace("\u2014", "-");
}

console.log(string);
```

My Expected Output is `SampleTestcase-Temp`;

Also, why Linux shows em-dash as a black diamond with a question mark and sometimes it showing like a comma?

Comment: How are you looking at this character in Linux? What application are you using?

Comment: You do not need to check if there is em-dash in the string when you want to replace it. Just use `string = string.replace(/\u2014/g, '-')`. Actually, melpomene's question is very relevant: how do you display the contents in Linux? Tool? Options?

Comment: Seems to me that your string is in 2 different encodings.

Comment: Use same code on Linux, it will work correctly, even if it displays differently (maybe font problem)

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the quotes passing only the Unicode to the regex argument (between `//`), and use `g` flag:

```js
console.log('SampleTestcase———————Temp'.replace(/\u2014/g, '-'));
```